# "these which" vs "the ones that"

Tags: pronouns, formality, determiners

I'm writing a research grant proposal and it was suggested to me that I replace words "these which" by "the ones that" in reference to scientific journals.

Here is the full sentence that I originally wrote:

> When choosing a scientific journal to submit my research outputs, I will prioritize these which allow for Open Access publication.

I was not given any explanation why I should make the change. I want to ask if there is indeed some difference in meaning between the two versions, or if one is more suitable for formal writing.

Comment: I'd be more tempted to use "those which".

Comment: @Esther Thank you, I must confess that I saw that thread before posting and decided to go for it nevertheless. I felt that both versions should be correct (perhaps up to "these" vs. "those", which is a separate discussion) myself and this is what the other thread also suggests. However, receiving such suggestion from my institutions proposal support made me think that I must be overlooking some subtlety here.

Comment: @Blazej I don't think so, and I would also prefer "those which," since it is more concise.